# Why does my honey always crystallized?

Tags: storage-method, honey

My honey always crystallizes no matter where I store it. I have some that hasn't been opened yet and it has crystallized. I have stored it in dark and warm places I tried cool places the outcome is the same. I know I can still use it but sometimes I haven't thought ahead and I didn't prepare the honey from being crystallized. Is there anything I can do to stop it from being crystallized?

Comment: Is it a bad thing? I only eat crystallized honey, as it has a more enjoyable texture to eat and liquid honey is messy.

Comment: If I get a jar of honey that is over prone to crystallizing, I'll add a few ml of water to it. That helps. You don't want to add a lot though, or you'll get into a water activity range where molds can grow.

Comment: The only change in recipes in using crystalized honey is that it's more prone to get more of it on spoon.

Answer (score 2):

That's normal for honey. When you buy good quality honey, it will always crystalize, no matter what you do. The speed and crystalization and the appearance of the crystals depends on the plant from which the honey was made.

If you want honey that doesn't crystalize, you can go to the supermarket and look at the cheaper honeys. If they are liquid in the supermarket already, there is a good chance that they have been treated in ways which prevent crystalization. Alternatively, you can buy products which are a mixture of bee honey and other sugars, which can also be formulated to not crystalize.

Comment: I bought this one at Costco and it crystallized even without being opened.

Comment: @GJ.Baker nothing unusual about that. Honey crystalizes on its own, no matter what you do.

Comment: Additionally, other than a bit of inconvenience, there's nothing wrong about crystallized honey, it's just as good as fresh for any purposes where the 'liquid state' isn't essential.

Answer (score 1):

found this on the back of my honey...

All pure honey will crystallise over time. This change is a sign of quality. It can be restored to its liquid state by loosening the lid and standing in hot water or removing the metal lid and heating gently in a microwave oven on the lowest power. However, don’t allow the honey temperature to exceed 40°C (104°F) as some of the goodness will be lost!